# Pandas: Spliting cells in one column according to a character, then adding the part to other columns via a conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there's an optimal way to perform this sort of action. I have a column of file paths, we'll call *C Drive*, which contains paths like

```
user\library\photos\item
```

This is a column in a dataframe, and the other columns are *Dir [1], Dir [2], ..., Dir [n], ITEM*

I want to split the cells in *C Drive* by "\", such that the last string is appended to the *ITEM* column, and the others are appended to the previous directories according to quantity.

My current coarse of action is a few While loops, but is there a better way to go about this in Pandas? I'm new to the library.

Would also like to mention that **I do know Pandas isn't made for this kind of stuff**, I'm using it in part to learn the library.

Cheers!

Comment: Provide sample data, please.  It helps to answer to the question and for future readers to understand what is going on.

Comment: It would also help to see your `while` loops, and at least an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function accessed by the `str` attribute of a Series to split your drive path into the constituent directories. Then convert the resulting Series of lists into a DataFrame. It can be done in one line, as follows:

```
dir_df = pd.DataFrame(df['C Drive'].str.split('\\').tolist())
dir_df.columns = ['Dir [{}]'.format(col) for col in dir_df.columns]
dir_df.columns[-1] = 'ITEM'
```

If you want the `'C Drive'` column in `dir_df` as well, you can simply add it like so:

```
dir_df['C Drive'] = df['C Drive']
```

By the way, you might want to escape '\'. Either convert it to '/' or '\' while reading the data in. Or else, weird things might happen.